# How should I do this? I can't use jUnit etc

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven, junit

I am working on a Spring Webflow programming using MySQL has the database.

I have some jUnit test cases that Maven runs on the build that uses a test database base not the dev database. we have a diff database for running the projects in dev then the builds.

I have some test data that I need setup in dev before running my project. I was using jUnit for it as part of the package/test in maven but the issue is that test is using diff xml and database.  how do you think I can go about making the project remove some delete in dev before running.. Does anyone know of any MySQL plugin for maven that will run a script before?

Comment: please consider changing your question's title to something more meaningful

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but I think you want to have certain data available in a DB when you run tests and that data is different in different environments.

Given you're already using maven I would suggest you set up build profiles for each environment, which will allow you to specify different DB connections, indeed if you implement an ORM such as hibernate, you can even get the DB schema and data dropped and recreated on each run in your test / dev environments.

Further more, in environments where you want the data to be specific to your test run and the data does not need to persist beyond the scope of your tests, implement an in memory DB, such as HSQL which can be seeded with data as required and wiped at the end, this will make your development environment more suitable for larger numbers of developers and remove the need for physical DB resources.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking about how to set up a database before running a Junit test. If so, I suggest you look at [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) and (as suggested in another answer) an in-memory database.